# Hibernate 5.2 opens new session for each item in lazily loaded collection

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa, java-8

I have one-to-many bi-directional mapping between two classes in Hibernate as below

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="version")
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

And other end

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="version_id")
private Version version;
```

Now i'm executing the following code

```
List<Product> products = version.getProducts();

// some lines below
int count = products.size();

// line 999
int num = products.stream().filter(x -> x::isValid).count();
```

Now when stream is retrieved from products collection, i can see that hibernate opens separate session for loading each item from the collection while filter operation is ongoing. How can i configure to fetch them in single session?

Here is my hibernate configuration

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
```

And i'm using JDK 8 with Hibernate 5.2.5

Comment: You can use this @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)

Comment: I can't use EAGER loading because, list of products is used at many places, so it'll only put unnecessary overhead everywhere else.

Comment: Try with @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

Comment: You can use this @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: I don't want to use a method which may have global effect (like using EAGER loading)